# Change an image when clicked to another image then the image resets back when another image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried searching everywhere and as I haven't a clue in javascript I don't really know what I'm doing.

this is the website I'm currently building.

[website link](http://thedesouzas.co.uk/artists.html)

the problem which I'm facing is that I want to be able to click on the name twist, and for it to change into another image:

twistnamehigh.png

and then when I click on another image,

for example, mello, I want the twistnamehigh.png to change back to twistname.png and then melloname.png to change to mellonamehigh.png.

here is the code which I want to work on...

```
<div id="artnavigation">

    <ul class="changeme">
    <img src="images/twistname.png" id="twist"  width="190px" height="49px" alt="MelloD" /></a>



    <img src="images/ashconname.png" id="ashcon" width="190px" height="49px" alt="MelloD" />


    <img src="images/melloname.png" id="mello" width="190px" height="49px" alt="MelloD" />
    </ul>

    </div>
```

This is the javascript which I have, i've used a method which I found on here that makes the name change the contents of the page.

```
$('.changeme img').on("click", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.about-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hide', '');

  $('.default-text').addClass('hide');
  $('.about-' + $id).removeClass('hide');
  $('div[class*=about]').not($class).addClass('hide');
});//@ sourceURL=pen.js
```

here is the whole code

```
    <div class="contentBox" id="home">
        <div class="blogContainer">

        <div id="artnavigation">

        <ul class="changeme">
        <img src="images/twistname.png" id="twist"  width="190px" height="49px" alt="MelloD" /></a>



        <img src="images/ashconname.png" id="ashcon" width="190px" height="49px" alt="MelloD" />


        <img src="images/melloname.png" id="mello" width="190px" height="49px" alt="MelloD" />
        </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="twistinfobox">


        <div class="about-twist">
            <div id="arrowtwist"></div>
            <div id="twistlogo">
            <div id="twistpicture"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="about-ashcon hide">
            <div id="arrowashcon"></div>
            <div id="ashlogo"></div>
            <div id="ashpicture"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="about-mello hide">
            <div id="arrowmello"></div>
            <div id="mellologo"></div>
            <div id="mellopicture"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="twistboxtext">
            <div class="about-twist">


            <p>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula consequat faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam bibendum, augue
            eu vehicula vulputate, felis eros sagittis arcu, ut elementum lectus arcu ac orci. Fusce placerat malesuada turpis, sit amet posuer
            e orci cursus a. Phasellus eget bibendum mauris, at aliquet mauris. Nam nisi orci, mattis nec ligula vitae, scelerisque suscipit massa.
            Curabitur vestibulum neque id ur
            na tempus pretium. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
                </br></br>
            Curabitur consequat ligula odio, et malesuada mi rutrum a. Nulla eget porttitor nibh. Cras vulputate eros orci, sit amet bibendum dui
            vulputate at. Duis et placerat urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas
            a odio dolor. Aenean vel iaculis massa. Curabitur in augue eget lacus placerat fermentum gravida euismod velit. Nulla varius ligula eu
            blandit venenatis. Donec a suscipit tellus. In dictum dolor lacinia, tincidunt orci quis, molestie nisl. Vestibulum auctor laoreet erat.
            Suspendisse ac metus ac elit vulputate pharetra.


            </p>
            </div>

            <div class="about-ashcon hide">


            <p>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula consequat faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam bibendum, augue
            eu vehicula vulputate, felis eros sagittis arcu, ut elementum lectus arcu ac orci. Fusce placerat malesuada turpis, sit amet posuer
            e orci cursus a. Phasellus eget bibendum mauris, at aliquet mauris. Nam nisi orci, mattis nec ligula vitae, scelerisque suscipit massa.
            Curabitur vestibulum neque id ur
            na tempus pretium. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
                </br></br>

            </p>
            </div>

            <div class="about-mello hide">


            <p>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula consequat faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam bibendum, augue
            eu vehicula vulputate, felis eros 


            </p>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>


<script>var __links = document.querySelectorAll('a');function __linkClick(e) { parent.window.postMessage(this.href, '*');} ;for (var i = 0, l = __links.length; i < l; i++) {if ( __links[i].getAttribute('target') == '_blank' ) { __links[i].addEventListener('click', __linkClick, false);}}</script>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/artist.js'></script>



        </div><!-- blogContainer End-->
    </div> <!-- contentBox End-->
```

Comment: I would do something like so : `if(myImg.src == image1){ myImg.src = image2 } else { myImg.src = image1 }` . This way it just flips between two images.

Answer (score 0):

you could the box-model properties to use a single image tag to load and preload both images you want to switch.

Example :

```
<img src="myimage" />
```

```
img {
height:50px;
width:100px;
padding:0;
background:url(myswitchimage);
}
img:hover {
height:0;
width:0;
padding:25px 50px ;/* img tag has still 50pxX100px size and you see its background only */
}
```

**[DEMO *by hovering*](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Joqzp)** of idea with a few transition effect possible .

---

If you add a `tabindex` attribute to `img` tag , then it can catch the click and you can use it to switch image for its `background`.

```
<img src="myimage" tabindex="0"/>
```

A second click can switch back as well if `pointer-events` is supported , else click out of image .

```
img {
height:50px;
width:100px;
padding:0;
background:url(myswitchimage);
}
img:focus {
height:0;
width:0;
padding:25px 50px ;/* img tag has still 50pxX100px size and you see its background only */
pointer-events:none;/* once it has focus, if you try clicking on it it again, it looses it */
}
```

**[DEMO 2 *by clicking*](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nifaq)**

Comment: I managed to get it working, changing twistname.png to twistnamehigh.png however, I need a id tag for the javascript to work, well that's how it's currently set to work. but when I added the id tag, along with some research, It appears it won't work...

any thoughts?

Comment: I answered my own question, I can't answer my own question as I don't have enough rep and I'm a new member :p will post the answer tomorrow!